# Tip / idea how can I get a generic context menu?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, contextmenu

I want to develop a generic contextmenu in wpf with mvvm. I would like to display it in each viewModel that have a listview with the style:  ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource  ListViewItemContainerStyle}".

The context menu will have 2 options that will be enabled or not depending on some constraints in each view Model. The enabled or not  will be managed by the canexecute of the command.

I have no problem if I put it in each view inside the listview, but I would like to have it only in one place other than in each listview. I have tried to put it in the ListViewItemContainerStyle but it shows an exception "it is not possible to add a System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu to a System.Object". Here is my code snippet

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemContainerStyle"
       TargetType="ListViewItem">
   .
   .
   .
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=Command}"
                          CommandParameter="AddNew">
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Static p:TextResources.New}" />
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=Command}"
                          CommandParameter="Delete">
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Static p:TextResources.Delete}" />
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
 .
 .
 .
```

Any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ContextMenu x:Shared="False" x:Key="ListViewContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=Command}"
                          CommandParameter="AddNew">
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Static p:TextResources.New}" />
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=Command}"
                          CommandParameter="Delete">
                    <MenuItem.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Static p:TextResources.Delete}" />
                    </MenuItem.Header>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>

<Style x:Key="ListViewItemContainerStyle"
       TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ListViewContextMenu}"/>
```

Comment: Now my problem is that the binding is done to the model, not to the viewmodel, so the commands won't execute. Thank you!